# RaycastHit return true all the time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I look at some object and press the button, I need to do something. When I do it for the first time, it works, but then I don't need to press the button again, I can just look at object. But player must look at object and press the button, not only look

```
private Collider thisCollider;
public int ActionNumber { get; private set; }

void Start ()
{
    thisCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && DoPlayerLookAtObject())
        ActionsList();
}

bool DoPlayerLookAtObject()
{
    int layerMask = 1 << 9;
    layerMask = ~layerMask;

    RaycastHit _hit;
    Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
    bool isHit = Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit, 2.0f, layerMask);        
    if (isHit && _hit.collider == thisCollider)
        return true; // this return true all the time after first interaction with object
    else
        return false;
}

public bool ActionsList()
{
    if (DoPlayerLookAtObject())
        switch (thisCollider.name)
        {
            case "barthender":   ActionNumber = 1; return true;
            case "doorToStreet": ActionNumber = 2; return true;
            default: Debug.Log("Error: Out of range"); break;
        }
    return false;
}
```

How I use it:

```
public OnMousePressCasino onMousePressCasinoBarthender;
public OnMousePressCasino onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet;

if (onMousePressCasinoBarthender.ActionNumber == 1 &&
    onMousePressCasinoBarthender.ActionsList())
    // do something

if (onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet.ActionNumber == 2 &&
    onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet.ActionsList())
    // do something
```

**Edit 1** Ignoring player's collider. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9lUdE_2snQ) from the game

[image]

Comment: It returns true because you're hitting yourself. `Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));` set the `Z` further away e.g. `2`. Besides that it always expects to hit itself ...

Comment: @m.rogalski I ignore player's collider here: `int layerMask = 1 << 9;
    layerMask = ~layerMask;`. I can hit the object. But when I want to hit it for the second time, I don't need press the button, I can just look at object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so basically you're settings you `ActionNumber` to ( let's say ) `1` and it stays at this value.

To fix this up you would have to set time based reset of that value or just use `Raycast` all the time in `Update` ( or `LateUpdate` ).
Another way would be to make use of [*event driven programming principles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) and just fire the event whenever your conditions are met and forget about setting some values.

Making it simple enough :

```
private Collider thisCollider;

public event EventHandler<MeEventArgs> OnAction;

void Start()
{
    thisCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        EventHandler<MeEventArgs> handler = OnAction;
        int actionIndex = DoPlayerLookAtObject();
        if ( handler != null && actionIndex >= 0)
        {
            handler(this, new MeEventArgs(actionIndex));
        }
    }
}    

int DoPlayerLookAtObject()
{
    int layerMask = 1 << 9;
    layerMask = ~layerMask;

    RaycastHit _hit;
    Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
    bool isHit = Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit, 2.0f, layerMask);        
    //if (isHit && _hit.collider == thisCollider)
    //    return true; // this return true all the time after first interaction with object
    //else
    //    return false;
    if (isHit && _hit.collider == thisCollider)
        return ActionList();

    return -1;
}

public int ActionsList()
{
    int result = -1;
    switch (thisCollider.name)
    {
        case "barthender":   result = 1; break;
        case "doorToStreet": result = 2; break;
        default: Debug.Log("Error: Out of range"); break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now create `MeEventArgs` :

```
public class MeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly int Action;

    public MeEventArgs(int actionIndex) : base()
    {
        Action = actionIndex;
    }
}
```

And to use this in code :

```
public OnMousePressCasino onMousePressCasinoBarthender;
public OnMousePressCasino onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet;

void Start()
{
    onMousePressCasinoBarthender.OnAction += MeAction;
    onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet.OnAction += MeAction;
}

void MeAction(object sender, MeEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Action == 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if (e.Action == 2)
    {
        // do something else.
    }
}
```

Comment: "Okay so basically you're settings you ActionNumber to ( let's say ) 1 and it stays at this value till you click another object". Not exactly. I put this script on each object, which I will hit in the future. So I can press object A, then press object B, and then I don't need to press object A, can just look at it, like and B. But thanks, i'll try it

Comment: @dima Yes. That's what I meant. Thank you for pointing my mistake :)